# Why address of arr and &arr are same in "C"

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, memory-address

By running this program on my computer, I'm getting same addresses. I'm for case of `array` and `&array[0]` I understand that name of `array` points to the address of first item in the `array`. And both of them are same.

But I'm ***unable*** to understand why name of `array` and `&array` points to the same address. What comes in my mind about this is that it will print the address of that pionter in which address of first item in array is stored.

#### Code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char arr[3];

    printf("array = %p\n", arr);
    printf("&array[0] = %p\n", &arr[0]);
    printf("&array = %p\n", &arr);

    return 0;
}
```

#### Output

```
array = 0061FF1D
&array[0] = 0061FF1D
&array = 0061FF1D
```

Comment: Arrays are just special in C. And when I say "special", I do mean it in a derogatory way. You just gotta learn the details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's important to note that while there are some similarities between arrays and pointers, they are *not* the same.

The name `array` does *not* point to the address of the first item.  It is in fact the *entire* array.  The confusion comes from the fact that in *most* contexts, the name of an array *decays* to a pointer to its first member.

Two notable places where array-to-pointer decay does *not* happen are when the array is the operand of either the `sizeof` operator or the address-of operator `&`.  Regarding the latter, an array is a contiguous set of objects, and (like any object) it has an address.  The address of an array is the same as the address of its first member, so `array` (when used in an expression, or equivalently `&array[0]`) and `&array` will have the same value but different types.

In your particular case, `&array[0]` has type `char *` while `&array` has type `char (*)[3]` (i.e. a pointer to an array of `char` of size 3).

Answer (score 0):

`1 + 2` and `1.0 + 2.0` both have the same value sum, yet of different types.  `printf("%p\n", arr); printf("%p\n", &arr); printf("%p\n", &arr[0]);` printing the same does not mean `arr` and `&arr` are the same thing - anymore than 3 and 3.0 differ in some attributes.